# How do I enter int elements in an array delimited by spaces in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I've been reading the several answers in this page regarding this issue, but none of them hace been useful to me. Also I read:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm

I want the code to read an N number of (INT) values in a single line and then store it in an array.

So far I did the following:

```
int main() {
 
    int n; 
    char arr[n];
    int arrInt[n];
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char* token;
    int i = 0;

    scanf("%n", &n);
    scanf("%c", arr);    
    token = strtok(arr, s);

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        arrInt[i] = atoi(token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `n` is not initialised so results in Undefined Behaviour for `arr` and `arrInt` declarations. If you need further help please describe what actual error or incorrect behaviour you are getting.

Comment: `scanf("%n", &n);` Why `%n`?

Comment: You have to assign to `n` before you can declare `char arr[n];`

Comment: `%c` only reads a single character. So that can't be what you want. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @jxvi could you please upload a sample input.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question says the numbers are delimited by spaces, one of the way to do this is by the following method

```
 int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    //for checking 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is usually good practice to check the return value of `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some points when you were writing your code.

```
char arr[n];
int arrInt[n];
```

A array cannot be defined in this way by C standards. This is a service that is removed by the standards but offered by compilers as an extension. This is called VLA. [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

```
scanf("%c", arr);
```

With this use, you can only get one character. You can't keep a string in the array. If you want to keep string in an array, you can review the following code.

```
char* sgets(char *p)
{
    char *pret = p;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        *p++ = (char)c;
    *p = '\0';

    return pret;
}
```

I wrote a code like this so that you can keep the strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "Hi Hello How Where";

    char *token = strtok(arr, " ");
    char **d_arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1);
    d_arr[0] = token;
    
    int count = 1;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        d_arr = realloc(d_arr, sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
        d_arr[count++] = token;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < count-1; ++i)
        printf("%s ", d_arr[i]);
}
```

I misunderstood the question. I hope what I write helps. :(